# Google+ sharing using UIActivityView - iOS 7

Tags: ios7, google-plus, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am Confused how to use `UIActivityView` With google+.

I want apply Google+ sharing like default Facebook, Twitter sharing with `UIActivityView`.

Can anyone give me example or some tutorial link?

Thanks.

Comment: can [this](https://github.com/lysannschlegel/GooglePlusShareActivity) help you? Have you tried something else?

Comment: I saw that code but it's using #import <GooglePlusShareActivity/GPPShareActivity.h> which is deprecated.No such class in google+ framework.

Comment: try this link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in the Google+ framework.

So I built a little wrapper for that very purpose: https://github.com/lysannschlegel/GooglePlusShareActivity

Comment: I am using google services for analytics and it makes all the those pods comes as duplicate symbols when compiling. I want to have Gplus activity but I want analytics and other google services. Do you have any workaround ?